# How to validate useful ECC algorithm in Java from command line?, before to use at IIB

Tags: java

I'm use a new certificate with ECC algorithm for implement on IIB Bus on enviroment prod, so before to do it, I have test on command line, so How to validate useful ECC algorithm in Java from command line?

Whats is the protocol to use, its another question for implement at IIB

Note: SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA with protocol SSL_TLSv2 for  Enables all SSL v3.0 and TLS v1.0, v1.1 and v1.2 protocols. Accepts SSLv3 or TLSv1 hello encapsulated in an SSLv2 format hello.

Comment: Please explain what solutions you have already tried/explored.

Comment: I was using iib 7, according to the documentation this version that runs with JDK 7, does not support ECC and RSA4096 certificates.
The solution was to update the version of IBM Integration Broker 10.0.0.22